# Couchbase fastest NoSQL (no Redis)? Can MongoDB performance be increased by using with some cache product? Is Couchbase so much faster than MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, couchdb, couchbase, nosql

Need to setup a server backend web-service and contemplating either some MongoDB solution or other NoSQL and cache concoction. I've read several articles indicating how Couchbase is so much faster than MongoDB which isn't a slouch itself. Here's for reference:

http://www.couchbase.com/press-releases/couchbase-dominates-cassandra-datastax-and-mongodb-newly-released-nosql-performance-benchmark

http://prnewswire.com/news-releases/mongodb-30-with-wired-tiger-new-benchmark-measures-performance-vs-couchbase-server-302-300053144.html

So my question how true is this? Has anyone else tested and can confirm such orders of magnitude performance difference?

If so, is there a way to improve MongoDB performance by integrating some cache for it? I think Couchbase is actually a 'cache' with CouchDB store added, how can MongoDB be used/integrated in some manner to provide similar performance?
Why not just use Couchbase if its better?

Well, I was concerned by reading many places about its "lack of documentation". Then I was alarmed by reading this:
"...Couchbase forum threads which are habitually abandoned by Couchbase reps when a developer points out a pretty huge flaw in their code, intentionally or unintentionally..."

http://scalabilitysolved.com/dont-use-couchbase-unless-you-really-really-want-to/

Just go to the bottom of that article linked above and read the entire comment at the bottom by Erutan. Basically if one goes to Couchbase website it does seem that the company is really pushing their "Enterprise" version mainly which is fine, but it is worry-some when people think that they might be purposefully not providing documentation and perhaps I misunderstood, but from what I gather from that Couchbase user's comments, some think that bugs might be left in the code "intentionally" to steer people to the enterprise version?
On the PLUS side, it does seem that all the code is Apache licensed so anyone is free to fix any bugs.

Anyway, for me, I was leaning towards MongoDB for various reasons, although performance was one of them, until happened on some couchbase benchmarks. Looking forward to some affirmations or challenges to these couchbase performance superiority claims and possible solutions to bolster MongoDB setup.
So is Couchbase way faster than any other non-memory proven/stable NoSql?

Comment: other link missing from post http://www.computing.co.uk/ctg/news/2330148/viber-explains-why-it-ditched-mongodb-and-redis-in-favour-of-couchbase

Comment: also, the (no redis) in the title should be interpreted as "Other than Redis or other In-Ram dbs..." just couldn't fit in less than 150characters

Comment: Benchmarks are useless, they have no relation what-so-ever to your scenario. Basing your technology decision on some random benchmark is the first sign of failure

Comment: I agree with @Sammaye , go test your own benchmarks and real world scenarios, they are both fast.

Comment: Expanding on Sammaye's excellent comment, I would like to add that your primary concern shouldn't be evaluating benchmarks if you can't. Both DBMS can be astonishing fast when used correctly. Choose the one you like more, even if you decide this by their website's design. Then, *thoroughly* learn how to use it. Voting to close as answers primarily will be opinion based.

Comment: Why is everyone so against benchmarks? They are very useful and usually a good test for performance of transactions per time based on equal 'resources'. I think I asked some valid questions. Should we go back and close all questions trying to compare nginx with apache or lighthttpd and just tell everyone benchmarks don't matter? First, I asked for "verification" of the Benchmarks I provided in links, second I asked for ways Mongodb performance might be "increased". They are two separate questions. Performance can usually always be 'increased' and I asked for ways to do that with Mongodb.

Comment: Take a look at PostgreSQL for example. They will normally always be slower than MySQL in benchmarks but I have found that in quite a few REAL scenarios, PostgreSQL out strips MySQL. That is the point. As for your argument on web servers: yes benchmarks are useless there. I use nginx so I am a proponent of it but I will willingly stand up and say that benchmarking apache and nginx is like benchmarking apples and oranges

Comment: In fact I think modern questions comparing nginx and apache for general scenarios are actually closed now

Answer (score 1):

CouchBase is fast but not the fastest one. I tested it, and in my scenarios **Tarantool** was 20% faster in terms of requests per second. Both of them are at order of magnitude faster than MongoDB. Maybe you should consider using one of the in-memory with persistence databases instead of MongoDB as your primary data store. One database is more consistent than a database and a cache layer on top of it.